# How to change a button's colour persistently in CSS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have buttons that I want to turn blue after pressed

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button.btn.btn-default").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #0F89BE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default" role="button" value="50">
            $50                              
</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" role="button" value="50">
            $100                              
</button>
```

I have multiple buttons and I want the selected button to turn blue (active). Similar to a radio button. Is there a simpler way to accomplish this? The jQuery doesn't work for me, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`.css` accepts a *CSS property name* and a value, for example

```
$(this).css('background-color', '#0F89BE')
```

It doesn't accept a new class you want to add. If you want to add a class to an element, use `addClass`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button.btn.btn-default").on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #0F89BE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default" role="button" value="50">
            $50                              
</button>
```

If you want to be able to click the button again to remove the class, use `toggleClass` instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button.btn.btn-default").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #0F89BE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default" role="button" value="50">
            $50                              
</button>
```

If you only want one button to have `.active` at a time, call `removeClass` on all buttons before using `addClass`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const btns = $("button.btn.btn-default");
  btns.on('click', function() {
    btns.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #0F89BE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default" role="button" value="50">
            $50                              
</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" role="button" value="50">
            $60                              
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. The last part of my question asks how to make it like a radio button. Sorry, I should've added more than one button to my example. I've changed that. I'm trying to make it like a radio button so only one is selected at any time.

Comment: See edit, call `removeClass` on all buttons before using `addClass`

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `css()` and `addClass()` in `jquery` to change you button color. `css()` adds styles to element while `addClass()` adds the class to the element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
//adding class
  $("button.btn.btn-default").on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
  
  // changing css
    $("#css-change").on('click', function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','#0F89BE');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #0F89BE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- By Adding Class-->
<button class="btn btn-default" role="button" value="50">
            $50                              
</button>

<!-- By changing css -->
<button id="css-change" class="btn btn-default" role="button" value="50">
            $50                              
</button>
```